# Using de Moivre's Theorem, express $(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{5}$ in Cartesian form $x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to express $(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{5}$ in Cartesian form $x+iy$, then the next question asks me to expand $(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{5}$ using the Binomial Theorem.

Would both give me the same answer? If so, I can do it using the Binomial Theorem, but not entirely sure how to do it using de Moivre's Theorem. I would need to find the modulus (which is $1$) and the $argument$, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Both the binomial theorem and DeMoivre's Theorem should give the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

By DeMoivre's Theorem:

$$(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))^{5}=(e^{i\theta})^5$$

$$(e^{i\theta})^5=e^{i5\theta}$$

$$e^{i5\theta}=\cos(5\theta)+i\sin(5\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

Moivre's Theorem states that if $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $z^n=||z||^n(\text{cos}(n\theta)+i\text{sin}(n\theta)), n \in \mathbb{N}$, we also know that $||z||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \Rightarrow z^5 = (x^2+y^2)^\frac{5}{2} \text{cos}(5\theta) + (x^2+y^2)^\frac{5}{2} \text{sin}(5\theta) i$. Since $||z||=1 \Rightarrow z^5 = \text{cos}(5\theta) + \text{sin}(5\theta) i$. The $arg(z)=\theta \Rightarrow arg(z^5)=5arg(z)=5\theta$